# How to convert Octal number to decimal number in arduino?

Tags: c, arduino

My problem is converting octal number to decimal number print using Arduino functions.

```
int octalNum = 33;
int decimalNumb = 0;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.println("Octal Number = "+octalNum);
    Serial.println("Decimal Number = "+decimalNumb);
}
```

Comment: If you want the compiler to interpret `33` as an octal number the let it start with a zero. Just type `033`, which corresponds to the decimal value 27. If you have another problem, please elaborate as the question is very unclear.

Comment: Sorry, what is `Serial.println()` ?  is this C or java code?  Please, don't tag this question as C if it is not a question about C language.

Answer (score 1):

Use the format parameter described in reference manual for [`println`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/println/):

```
Serial.println(analogValue, OCT);  // print as an ASCII-encoded octal
```

Something like:

```
Serial.print("Octal Number = ");
Serial.println(octalNum , OCT);
```

**Output:**

```
Octal Number = 41
```

as the octal value of the decimal number `33` is `41`.
If instead you meant defining `octalNum` using an octal constant, in the first place, just remember that octal constants are defined inserting an heading `0`:

```
int octalNumber = 033; // decimal 27
```

---

Please note how `OctalNum` is just stored as an integer, and this has nothing to do with the way is printed later.

Comment: Also note that `int octalNum = 33;` will treat `33` as a *decimal* number, so the result will be 41 octal.

Comment: @Fred Larson 33 is octal number how to convert octal to decimal number

Comment: @MeetBhavsar numbers... are numbers. Don't be confused between the value of an integer and its representation. All numbers are stored in memory as a sequence of bytes, so they'll be able to be represented any way you like. Defining `int octalNumber = 33;` 33 will be its decimal value. If you want define an octal constant you have to insert an heading 0: `int octalNumber = 033;`

Comment: @MeetBhavsar I've edited a bit my answer according to my previous comment.

Answer (score -1):

```
int octalNum = 33;
int decimalNumb = 0;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
      Serial.println("Octal Number = "+octalNum);
     Serial.println("Decimal Number = "+octalToDecimal(decimalNumb));
}
static int octalToDecimal(int n) 
{ 
        int num = n; 
        int dec_value = 0; 
        int base = 1; 
        int temp = num; 
        while (temp > 0) { 
            int last_digit = temp % 10; 
            temp = temp / 10; 
            dec_value += last_digit * base; 
            base = base * 8; 
        } 
        return dec_value; 
}
```

Comment: `octalToDecimal(any_negative_value)` returns 0.  Use `unsigned` to avoid dealing with neagtive numbers.